# what is the calculus of constructions

Tags: type-theory

I have to write about something called the *Calculus of Constructions* for a term paper, and I have no idea what it is. (I've looked on Wikipedia, but it's all jargon to me. Can someone explain to me (in very basic terms) what it is? (I'm still in high school by the way)

Comment: Are you familiar with the lambda calculus?  If not, this is probably going to take a while.

Comment: i'm still in precalculus
sorry :(

Comment: How did this come to be assigned to a high-school class?  This seems way too advanced for any high-school class.

Comment: i have to write about it for a term paper loll

Comment: this is the problem i have to base it off off:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2016_USAMO_Problems/Problem_1

Comment: I didn't see anything there about the calculus of constructions?  Are you looking at IMO problems?  That's an international competition!

Comment: i found the term in a solution, so i figured that to understand where I should begin with the problem I should understand what the calculus of construction was.
I think the term that I found most associated with calculus of constructions was "inductive constructions"

Comment: "Inductive construction" is being used in a general sense of "a construction that's inductively defined". While not technically unrelated to the Calculus of Inductive Constructions (CIC), in no way do you need to understand anything about it to understand what the page you referenced is talking about. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition) is more what they are talking about. Your question is a bit like seeing "function" referred to and then thinking that you need to know about [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis).

Comment: On the flip side, while completely unnecessary to your purposes, CIC and related systems, are interesting if you are interested in math (and particularly logic). Since, CIC is embodied in the proof assistant [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/), it is possible to learn on your own and is feasible (though *very* challenging and still a multi-year project) for a high school student to learn how to use it. Tooling means when you are right or wrong, you know. [Logitext](http://logitext.mit.edu/tutorial) is a much simpler introduction to some of the more basic ideas.

Comment: sorry, but what's a "construction"? I haven't heard that term used in this kind of context before.

Comment: It's not being used in any particularly formal sense. In your link, a finite set is being built, that is, it is being constructed. If you read Euclid's Elements, besides theorems (ending in QED), he also talks about constructions (ending in [QEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.#Q.E.F.)). For example, given a line segment you can construct an equilateral triangle from it with a compass and ruler. (Wikipedia and I picked the same example...) If you ask a mathematician what exactly does and does not constitute a "construction", few will give you straight answer.